# CGO: handle SIGTERM / SIGABRT

Tags: c, go, signals, cgo

I am calling [a](https://github.com/MetricPanda/fast-poly2tri) c library that uses [assert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) in many places. This is a problem for me because I don't want my application to terminate when an assert fails.

Setting the `NDEBUG` flag to disable the asserts doesn't help as it just leads to a segfault.

Here is what I've got so far but the SIGTERM is not caught.

```golang
// Redefine the MPE_Assert macro to use SIGTERM since SIGABRT cannot be stopped.
// #include <signal.h>
// #define MPE_Assert(_Expression) (void) ((!!(_Expression)) || (raise(SIGTERM)))
import "C"
func Poly2Tri(verts [][2]float32, holes [][][2]float32) [][2]float32 {
    sig := make(chan os.Signal, 10)
    result := make(chan [][2]float32)
    defer signal.Stop(sig)

    go func() {
        // Notify for all signals
        signal.Notify(sig)
        result <- poly2Tri(verts, holes)
    }()

    select {
    case res := <-result:
        return res
    case <-sig:
        return [][2]float32{}
    }
}
```

So, how do I allow the library to exit when an assert fails but allow my application to continue?

*I'dont think that the* `poly2Tri` *function is relevant for this issue but I can add it if needed.*

Comment: Trying to catch and recover from an assertion failure is a bad idea. The trick is to avoid tripping an `assert` in the first place. Also as you noticed `assert` works in DEBUG builds only. So you will never be able to run a release build, if you rely on `assert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to handle `SIGTERM` and `SIGABRT` using [`signal.Notify`](https://beta.pkg.go.dev/os/signal#Notify) in native Go code or [`sigaction`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) in C (perhaps set up via a cgo call).

However, a `SIGTERM` or `SIGABRT` handler should *not* stop the process from terminating — it can do some best-effort logging (perhaps to aid in debugging), or flush intermediate output (to reduce the amount of work lost), but in general an `assert` failure may indicate that the program is badly broken in some way — if it continues to run, it may produce arbitrarily wrong output (e.g. due to memory corruption), or segfault (because the program does not expect the call to `assert` to return), or deadlock (because the `assert` indicates a broken locking invariant).

If you are having trouble with a program running into `assert` failures, rather than trying to trap and suppress those failures, it may be more productive to look for ways to reproduce them (such as by [fuzzing](https://golang.org/issue/44551) your program's inputs, or logging a trace of what the program is doing before the failure). Then you can fix the underlying cause of the `assert` failures, and you won't need to try to recover from them.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion that preventing assert failures is basically the only good option even when it requires additional checks / processing time.